# Javascript convert String to Object property

Tags: javascript

i want to build my own `PROP` function just like what `Jquery` does, but in pure `Java script`.

this is my code :

```
<input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="LOGIN">

function prop(el, dom, boolean) {

    var convert = eval(dom);
    el.convert = boolean;
    console.log(convert);
}

var x = document.getElementById("submitButton");

prop(x, "disabled", true);
```

How to convert string into object property? I heard that `eval` will be useful? But why did i got the below error?

```
ReferenceError: disabled is not defined
```

what's wrong with my code?

Comment: use - `el[dom]`, or `el.setAttribute(dom,value)` to manipulate `properties` of an `el`.

Comment: ^ You should use this.

Comment: wow BatScream, your method works perfect! thank  you so much!!!! you are A W E S O M E, anyway, i wonder what kind person that give me down votes for this questions lol

Comment: @BatScream - Why are the things you say in this comment (which holds the best answer) nowhere to be found in your actual answer?

Comment: @JimboJonny - have included it now. I thought the link and the comments  would have sufficed. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should **not** use [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) to convert property names into properties. Use [`Property accessors`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

e.g., `el[dom]` or `el.dom`.

If the `Object` is an `HTML` element, you could use the [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) and `getAttribute` methods that are available.

when you pass in a string as argument to eval, it tries to represent the string as java script code.

Here, you have passed in a string `disabled`.

It gets represented as:

```
disabled;
```

The interpreter now tries to locate a variable named `disabled`. Since `disabled` is not a variable we have defined in the context, it throws the error: `ReferenceError: disabled is not defined`.

To validate this, try defining a variable and then invoking the `eval()` function on it.

```
var disabled = 10;
console.log(eval("disabled"));
```

prints: `#10`

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're trying to evaluate what "disabled" alone is to.
`eval("document.getElementById('submitButton').disabled")` would work.

Comment: This one also working! thanks Aiman Al-Eryani. you're the best!!